# TinyMCE and RoxyFileBrowser

Tags: php, laravel, tinymce, text-editor, roxy-fileman

I am using TinyMCE and RoxyFileBrowser to create text files with images and saved them in a database.(only the html content of textarea). When I am reloading the saved content from database the images are not loading. when I checked I find out in TinyMCE html sorce code image src is incorrect. So I edit the RoxyFileBrowser conf.json as

```
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "/",
```

Now in the TinyMCE Insert/Edit Image window source URL is displayed as needed. But still the tinyMCE  html content has wrong image src url.

Source URL=/fileman/....... - which is needed one
[image]

img src="../fileman/....." which is incorrect
[image]

What is the reason for this error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally I found the answer.

The problem is with tinymce is trying to use relative URLs. So turn it off in tinymce.init function

```
    relative_urls : false,
```

Answer (score 0):

Example:     "RETURN_URL_PREFIX":   "http://localhost:59184/"
"RETURN_URL_PREFIX" is your domain